# SQL - group by column, count into a single row

Tags: sql

I'm trying take the result from a `group by <col>`  into a single row, as my graphing library requires a single row for visualizing a stacked bar.  For context, I'm using Presto/AWS Athena.

My query is `SELECT result, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY result`

Essentially

```
result  | count
skipped | 12
passed  | 13
failed  | 2
```

Into

```
skipped | passed | failed
12      | 13     | 2
```

Comment: What you're looking for is transposing rows into columns. Don't have the free moment to go into detail, but that should point you in the right direction

Comment: wrap the whole thing in another query - `select max(case when result='skipped then count end),... from (original query) t`

Comment: By the way, I hope you don't really have a column named `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small set like this, conditional aggregation is simplest.

```
select
max (case when result = 'skipped' then cnt end) as skipped,
max(case when result = 'passed' then cnt end) as passed,
max(case when result = 'failed' then cnt end) as failed
from
(SELECT result, count(*) cnt FROM table GROUP BY result) t
```